# Filter/Search Table For Exact Match

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm using an effective JavaScript table search filter but when adding in numbers I only want exact matches.  How do I accomplish only filtering on the exact search?

Example Basic table:

> ```
> <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for counts">
>
> <table id="myTable">
>   <tr class="header">
>     <th style="width:50%;">Counts</th>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>1</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>19</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>111</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>1</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>11</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>100</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>10</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>20</td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> ```

My actual Javascript:

> ```
> function myFunction() {       var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;    
> input = document.getElementById("myInput");    
> filter = input.value.toUpperCase();    
> table =document.getElementById("myTable");    
> tr =table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
>
>     query   for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
>     td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
>     if (td) {
>       txtValue = td.textContent;
>       if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
>         tr[i].style.display = "";
>       } else {
>         tr[i].style.display = "none";
>       }
>     }    } }
> ```

How can I get I only return exact matches in my search?

Comment: Use `===` instead of `indexOf`?

Comment: This is want I thought, but I've tried this but I can seem to get it to work.

Comment: Check the answers - did any of them work for you? (if so, you may consider marking one as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved)

Answer (score 0):

Checking whether the `txtValue === filter` works just fine. Note that because the `td`s don't contain words, there's no need for `toUpperCase()`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase() === filter) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for counts">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:50%;">Counts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to display all results when the input is empty:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent;
      if (!filter || txtValue === filter) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for counts">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:50%;">Counts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, to be somewhat more elegant:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const { value } = document.querySelector('#myInput');
  document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td').forEach((td) => {
    td.parentElement.style.display =
    (!value || td.textContent === value)
    ? ''
    : 'none';
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for counts">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:50%;">Counts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For an exact match, use the `===` operator. Also no need to use `toUpperCase` since only numbers are being compared.

Also, querying for `tr` is redundant as it would be more efficient to retrieve all the `td`s.

```js
const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);

function myFunction(){
  const searchWord = this.value;
  table
    .querySelectorAll("td")
    .forEach(td=>{
      if(searchWord.length === 0){
         td.style.display = "block";
      }
      else if(td.textContent.trim() !== searchWord){
        td.style.display = "none";
      } else td.style.display = "block";
    });
    
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput"  placeholder="Search for counts">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:50%;">Counts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When index of filter <-1 you have to set display value to block

```
 if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "block";
  }
```