# How to create script for exact search excluding % sign

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm creating a table that I'd like to search by he first column (number + % sign). I've got it set up so I can search for the number, but need it to return the exact number without necessitating the % to be included.

I've found a [close solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700692/filter-search-table-for-exact-match), but it doesn't account for excluding the % in the search.

Here's an portion of the table along with the search script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search ABV" title="Type in ABV">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:100%;">ABV</th>
    <th><strong>1 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>2 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>3 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>4 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>5 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>6 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>7 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>8 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>9 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>10 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>11 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>12 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>13 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>14 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>15 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>16 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>17 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>18 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>19 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>20 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>21 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>22 oz.</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>3%</strong></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>128</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>143</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>165</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>3.5%</strong></td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>97</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>114</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>149</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>167</td>
    <td>175</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>193</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4%</strong></td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>130</td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>170</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>190</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>210</td>
    <td>220</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.5%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>124</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>147</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>169</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>192</td>
    <td>203</td>
    <td>214</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td>237</td>
    <td>248</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.6%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>58</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td>81</td>
    <td>92</td>
    <td>104</td>
    <td>115</td>
    <td>127</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>161</td>
    <td>173</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>196</td>
    <td>207</td>
    <td>219</td>
    <td>230</td>
    <td>242</td>
    <td>253</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.7%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>71</td>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>106</td>
    <td>118</td>
    <td>130</td>
    <td>141</td>
    <td>153</td>
    <td>165</td>
    <td>177</td>
    <td>188</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>212</td>
    <td>224</td>
    <td>235</td>
    <td>247</td>
    <td>259</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.8%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>84</td>
    <td>96</td>
    <td>108</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>144</td>
    <td>156</td>
    <td>168</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>192</td>
    <td>204</td>
    <td>216</td>
    <td>228</td>
    <td>240</td>
    <td>252</td>
    <td>264</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.9%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>74</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>147</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>172</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>196</td>
    <td>209</td>
    <td>221</td>
    <td>233</td>
    <td>245</td>
    <td>258</td>
    <td>270</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>5%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>125</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>163</td>
    <td>175</td>
    <td>188</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td>238</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>263</td>
    <td>275</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>5.1%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>77</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to alter the table layout here to add attributes for example?

Comment: A quick and dirty solution is modify your if statement to look if the textValue == the number + %. So something like **if (txtValue.toUpperCase() == (filter + "%")) {**

Comment: @imvain2 that did it!  Is there a way to have the whole chart reappear once the text is cleared?

Comment: @mulvatron I created an answer with an updated if statement

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would simply update the if statement to compare the value of the TD along with the % attached to the filter variable. Plus adding an || or statement for an empty filter allows you to reset the table too.

**if (txtValue.toUpperCase() == (filter + "%") || filter == "") {**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase() == (filter + "%") || filter == "") {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search ABV" title="Type in ABV">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:100%;">ABV</th>
    <th><strong>1 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>2 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>3 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>4 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>5 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>6 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>7 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>8 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>9 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>10 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>11 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>12 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>13 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>14 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>15 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>16 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>17 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>18 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>19 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>20 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>21 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>22 oz.</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>3%</strong></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>128</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>143</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>165</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>3.5%</strong></td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>97</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>114</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>149</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>167</td>
    <td>175</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>193</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4%</strong></td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>130</td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>170</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>190</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>210</td>
    <td>220</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.5%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>124</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>147</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>169</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>192</td>
    <td>203</td>
    <td>214</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td>237</td>
    <td>248</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.6%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>58</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td>81</td>
    <td>92</td>
    <td>104</td>
    <td>115</td>
    <td>127</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>161</td>
    <td>173</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>196</td>
    <td>207</td>
    <td>219</td>
    <td>230</td>
    <td>242</td>
    <td>253</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.7%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>71</td>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>106</td>
    <td>118</td>
    <td>130</td>
    <td>141</td>
    <td>153</td>
    <td>165</td>
    <td>177</td>
    <td>188</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>212</td>
    <td>224</td>
    <td>235</td>
    <td>247</td>
    <td>259</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.8%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>84</td>
    <td>96</td>
    <td>108</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>144</td>
    <td>156</td>
    <td>168</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>192</td>
    <td>204</td>
    <td>216</td>
    <td>228</td>
    <td>240</td>
    <td>252</td>
    <td>264</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.9%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>74</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>147</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>172</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>196</td>
    <td>209</td>
    <td>221</td>
    <td>233</td>
    <td>245</td>
    <td>258</td>
    <td>270</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>5%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>125</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>163</td>
    <td>175</td>
    <td>188</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td>238</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>263</td>
    <td>275</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>5.1%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>77</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using data attributes to both contain the values and to toggle the visual with CSS - whatever you want that to be.  Here I just add some color to the rows found/not found.
Now this can be HTML `table` or a `div` or whatever without changing the code

```js
function keyUpEventHandler(event) {
  const input = event.currentTarget;
  const filterValue = input.value.toUpperCase();
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  const searchRows = table.querySelectorAll(".searchable-row");
  Array.from(searchRows).forEach((rowElement) => {
    rowElement.dataset.hasMatch = "no-match";
  });
  Array.from(searchRows).filter(rowElement =>
    rowElement.querySelector(".search-column").dataset.searchValue.toUpperCase() === filterValue
  ).forEach((rowElement) => {
    rowElement.dataset.hasMatch = "has-match";
  });
}
const searchABV = document.getElementById("myInput");
searchABV.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpEventHandler, false);
```

```css
.searchable-row[data-has-match="no-match"] {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  background-color: #ddddff;
}

.searchable-row[data-has-match="has-match"] {
  border: solid green 1px;
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search ABV" title="Type in ABV">

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:100%;">ABV</th>
      <th><strong>1 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>2 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>3 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>4 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>5 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>6 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>7 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>8 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>9 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>10 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>11 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>12 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>13 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>14 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>15 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>16 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>17 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>18 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>19 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>20 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>21 oz.</strong></th>
      <th><strong>22 oz.</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="3"><strong>3%</strong></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>128</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>143</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>165</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="3.5"><strong>3.5%</strong></td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>97</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>114</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>149</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>167</td>
    <td>175</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>193</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="4"><strong>4%</strong></td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>130</td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>170</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>190</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>210</td>
    <td>220</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="4.5"><strong>4.5%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>124</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>147</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>169</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>192</td>
    <td>203</td>
    <td>214</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td>237</td>
    <td>248</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="4.6"><strong>4.6%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>58</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td>81</td>
    <td>92</td>
    <td>104</td>
    <td>115</td>
    <td>127</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>161</td>
    <td>173</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>196</td>
    <td>207</td>
    <td>219</td>
    <td>230</td>
    <td>242</td>
    <td>253</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="4.7"><strong>4.7%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>71</td>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>106</td>
    <td>118</td>
    <td>130</td>
    <td>141</td>
    <td>153</td>
    <td>165</td>
    <td>177</td>
    <td>188</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>212</td>
    <td>224</td>
    <td>235</td>
    <td>247</td>
    <td>259</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="4.8"><strong>4.8%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>84</td>
    <td>96</td>
    <td>108</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>144</td>
    <td>156</td>
    <td>168</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>192</td>
    <td>204</td>
    <td>216</td>
    <td>228</td>
    <td>240</td>
    <td>252</td>
    <td>264</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="4.9"><strong>4.9%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>74</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>147</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>172</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>196</td>
    <td>209</td>
    <td>221</td>
    <td>233</td>
    <td>245</td>
    <td>258</td>
    <td>270</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="5"><strong>5%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>125</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>163</td>
    <td>175</td>
    <td>188</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td>238</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>263</td>
    <td>275</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable-row">
    <td class="search-column" data-search-value="5.1"><strong>5.1%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>77</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When filtering, you have two options:

- Exact matches
- Cell visibility

```js
const
  filterText = document.querySelector('#filterText'),
  exactMatch = document.querySelector('#exactMatch'),
  hideCells = document.querySelector('#hideCells'),
  table = document.querySelector('#myTable');

const findAll = (selector, parent = document) =>  
  [...parent.querySelectorAll(selector)];

function doFilter() {
  const hide = hideCells.checked;
  const filter = filterText.value.trim().toUpperCase();
  findAll('tr', table).slice(1).forEach(row => {
    const showRow =
      (filter === '') ||
      (filter.length && findAll('td', row).reduce((acc, td, index) => {
        const value = td.textContent.toUpperCase();
        const matches = exactMatch.checked
          ? value === filter
          : value.includes(filter);
        td.style.visibility = !hide || (hide && matches) || index === 0
          ? 'visible'
          : 'hidden';
        return matches ? true : acc;
      }, false));
    row.style.display = showRow ? '' : 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#myTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: hsl(120, 75%, 90%);
}

#myTable tr td:nth-child(even) {
  background: #DDD;
}

#myTable tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: hsl(120, 75%, 80%);
}

#myTable .header {
  background: #AAA !important;
}

#myTable .header th:nth-child(even) {
  background: #888 !important;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="search" id="filterText" onInput="doFilter()" placeholder="Search ABV" title="Type in ABV" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="exactMatch" onChange="doFilter()" />
  <label for="exactMatch">Exact Match</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hideCells" onChange="doFilter()" />
  <label for="hideCells">Hide Cells</label>
</form>
<hr />
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:100%;">ABV</th>
    <th><strong>1 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>2 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>3 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>4 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>5 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>6 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>7 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>8 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>9 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>10 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>11 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>12 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>13 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>14 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>15 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>16 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>17 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>18 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>19 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>20 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>21 oz.</strong></th>
    <th><strong>22 oz.</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>3%</strong></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>128</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>143</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>165</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>3.5%</strong></td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>97</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>114</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>149</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>167</td>
    <td>175</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>193</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4%</strong></td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>130</td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>170</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>190</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>210</td>
    <td>220</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.5%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>124</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>147</td>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>169</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>192</td>
    <td>203</td>
    <td>214</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td>237</td>
    <td>248</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.6%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>58</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td>81</td>
    <td>92</td>
    <td>104</td>
    <td>115</td>
    <td>127</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>161</td>
    <td>173</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>196</td>
    <td>207</td>
    <td>219</td>
    <td>230</td>
    <td>242</td>
    <td>253</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.7%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>71</td>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>106</td>
    <td>118</td>
    <td>130</td>
    <td>141</td>
    <td>153</td>
    <td>165</td>
    <td>177</td>
    <td>188</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>212</td>
    <td>224</td>
    <td>235</td>
    <td>247</td>
    <td>259</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.8%</strong></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>84</td>
    <td>96</td>
    <td>108</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>144</td>
    <td>156</td>
    <td>168</td>
    <td>180</td>
    <td>192</td>
    <td>204</td>
    <td>216</td>
    <td>228</td>
    <td>240</td>
    <td>252</td>
    <td>264</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>4.9%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>74</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>135</td>
    <td>147</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>172</td>
    <td>184</td>
    <td>196</td>
    <td>209</td>
    <td>221</td>
    <td>233</td>
    <td>245</td>
    <td>258</td>
    <td>270</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>5%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>113</td>
    <td>125</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>163</td>
    <td>175</td>
    <td>188</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>213</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td>238</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>263</td>
    <td>275</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>5.1%</strong></td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>77</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```